# ElastiSearch combine result set of two queries

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have below data structure in ElastiSearch.

```
[{
  "name": "Kapil",
  "age": 32,
  "hobbies": ["Cricket", "Football", "Swimming"]
},
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 33,
  "hobbies": ["Baseball", "Football", "Swimming"]
},
{
  "name": "Vick",
  "age": 30,
  "hobbies": ["Baseball", "Karate", "Swimming"]
}]
```

I want to get all records from the data in following order:

1. Get all users which has `Football` as hobby and sort them by age desc.
2. Get all other users sort by age desc.

So expecting result in following order John, Kapil and Vick.

I used below query to get result for #1.

```
{
   "size": 500,
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "hobbies.keyword": "Football"
          }
        }
       ]
     }
   },
   "sort": [
    {
      "age": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and used below for point #2

```
{
   "size": 500,
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "must_not": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "hobbies.keyword": "Football"
          }
        }
       ]
     }
   },
   "sort": [
    {
      "age": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With above, I am not able to maintain the paging logic. It also requires me to execute both queries separately. Can Someone please help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {} <-- retrieve all docs
            },
            "should": { <-- give higher score to docs that match this clause
                "match_phrase": {
                    "hobbies.keyword": "Football"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        "_score", <-- sort by doc score first
        {
            "age": { <-- when score is equal then sort by age
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nick. However, in my case, I am not getting same score for all the documents which contains `Football`. So sorting by age isn't working

Comment: Hmm, I've run this query against your data in the description and it worked fine to me. Please update your question with documents that contain `Football` and have different score in result